# TSQL - Invalid Column Name RowNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does it say `'Invalid Column Name'` for the RowNumber in `WHERE`.

```
SELECT Id, Name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM Folks
WHERE RowNumber=3
```

While can be used with `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT Id, Name
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM Folks
ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
```

Comment: Besides the order of operations, you have a typo - missing a comma.

Comment: I missed the comma when I am typing the question here.

Comment: I assume it's not duplicate. Accepted Answer indicated the alias was missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT Id, Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS 'RowNumber'
         FROM    Folks
        ) AS A
WHERE   RowNumber = 3
```

Comment: Updated the answer... Try now...

Comment: 'AS A' got it done. What's the idea behind?

Comment: It is just a alias name...

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a comma:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (SELECT Id, Name,
---------------------^
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
      FROM Folks f
     ) f
WHERE RowNumber = 3;
```

Plus you cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause at the same level.  A subquery or CTE solves that problem.

And, it is best not to use single quotes for column aliases.  You should use single quotes only for string and date constants.  In this case, `rownumber` doesn't need to be escaped at all.

Comment: _you cannot use a column alias in a where clause at the same level_ Thank you, this is one of those dumb things I should have known and forgot.